# How to exclude Class Properties in OpenCover?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, opencover

For example I have a simple POCO like so:

```
public class Customer
{
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I want to exclude the properties that follow this pattern.
Note that I cannot exclude the whole class because in future I might add a method that needs coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information you need us in the wiki

https://github.com/opencover/opencover/wiki/Usage

In this instance `-skipautoprops` is the switch you need.